# Debugging Java Webstart: System Process is opening tons of ports

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm trying to debug a Java Webstart application which is causing the System Process with pid 0 to open thousands of tcp ports between 1000 and ~4000. The remote host is always localhost port 80, on which an Apache webserver is listening. The state of all connections is TIME_WAIT and there is no traffic at all.

After two days I have still no idea what's causing this behaviour since the application is running fine without using Java Webstart.

This is my JNLP file generated by Netbeans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:80/cwticket/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>CWTicket</title>
    <vendor>tstegman</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>CWTicket</description>
    <description kind="short">CWTicket</description>

</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.5+"/>
<jar href="CWTicket.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/asm.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/asm-attrs.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ehcache-1.2.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jdbc2_0-stdext.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jta.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-tools.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-entitymanager.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javassist.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/args4j-2.0.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar"/>
</resources>

<application-desc main-class="de.cw.cwticket.gui.TicketExplorerFrame">

</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Thank you very much for any hints!

Edit: The operating system is Windows XP SP3.

Comment: I think I'd try a rootkit scanner:  PID 0 is idle proc.  

Try GMER http://www.gmer.net/ 
or 
TDSSKiller http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/solutions?qid=208283363

Comment: Forget what I said earlier.  I missed the bit about connecting to localhost.  Whatever you are using to find connections might not be able to determine which PID is making connection and is defaulting PID to zero. 
//

Take out the update check and see if behavior changes.  Maybe the implementation is sub-optimal.  BTW, what java version ?

Comment: And by "implementation" I meant the JRE Java Web Start

Comment: I'm using Sysinternals TCPView to look for connections. Is there any other tool I could try, which does a better job?

The Java version is 1.6.0 Update 22 from Oracle.

Comment: Removing the update check didn't change anything. I'm also a little bit confused about the fact, that the port requesting starts even before the application does any network related stuff and keeps going on after the virtual machine has terminated.

Comment: Could try a brute force approach to see what is going on.  Try tracing `javaws` with `Process Monitor` (download here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)
Filter on  command line conmtaining`javaws`.
Set

Comment: Javaw.exe constantly queries the registry key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\AutoDetect' which is 0x1 (tried to change it to 0x0 with no luck) and sends a TCP packet with 176 bytes from localhost:xyz to localhost:80. Next step is a TCP Receive with 1627 bytes to localhost:xyz. The port gets closed and its state changes to TIME_WAIT. Is there any way to capture these packets? It seems Wireshark isn't able to capture from 127.0.0.1.